# Example of $a_{n}$ such that $\lim_{n\to\infty }a_{n}=0$, and there is a convg subsequence $\left ( S_{k_{n}} \right )$ of $\left ( S_{n}\right )$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, power-series

I'm having trouble to find an example of a sequence $\left ( a_{n} \right )$ such that $\lim_{n\to\infty }a_{n}=0$, and there is a convergent subsequence $\left ( S_{k_{n}} \right )$ of $\left (  S_{n}\right )$, but $\sum a_{n}$ diverges.

We denote $S_{k}=a_{1}+a_{2}+\cdot \cdot \cdot +a_{k}$

My first approach was finding $\left (  S_{n}\right )$ that is bounded but divergent (because this will lead us to conclude that there is a convergent subsequence). For example, there is $S_{n}=sin(n)$, but then $\lim_{n\to\infty }a_{n}\neq 0$. So, it fails to be our example.

Is there a better way to find such examples?

Comment: @rubikscube09 That won't work. $S_n$ is always a sum of **all** $a_n$ from $a_1$ to $a_n$.

Comment: @5xum Right, I'm having trouble because of that part. If it was a sum of subsequence, it wouldn't be any problem, but it's about subsequence of $S_{n}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**:

Try to construct $a_n$ such that $S_n$ oscilates from $1$ to $-1$ and back to $1$ and back to $-1$. Each oscilation will have to take more steps, since $a_n$ will have to be smaller and smaller, but you can afford it, you can have $a_n$ stuck on a particular value for how ever long you want.

Comment: I could only think of something like $S_{n}=sin(n^2)$. But this still doesn't give me convergent $a_{n}$. Could you give me more hints?

Comment: @john Yeah, don't try to construct it via a simple equation. Don't try to make it pretty, just try to make it work. Also, don't try to construct $S_n$. Try to construct $a_n$, and construct it so that $S_n$ oscilates from $1$ to $-1$.

Comment: Oh, I finally got it. If $a_{n}=-1,1,-1/2,-1/2,1/2,1/2,-1/4,-1/4,-1/4,-1/4,1/4,1/4,1/4,1/4,$ and so on, this will give us $S_{n}$ that is bounded between 0 and -1, so there is a convergent subsequence. Does this seem similar to your answer?

Comment: @john YES!!! Oh it makes me so happy that you were able to find the construction on your own and that the hints were enough. Well done!